# Nothing being returned by JQuery and Flask?

Tags: jquery, python, html, mysql, ajax

I'm writing some code to basically make username and password box using mysql, jquery and flask. Currently my mysql database is 100% working but Flask won't return values to the JQuery so I am unable to update a div in my html. EDIT: Using console.log there is an error that is just ""

This is my currently method in Flask thats having trouble

```
@app.route("/authentication/")
def validation():
    username = {"value": request.args.get('echoValue')}
    password = {"value": request.args.get('echoValue2')}
    cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * from _accounts where Username='" + str(username['value']) + "'   and Password='" + str(password['value']) + "'")
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    if data is None:
        return "Username or Password is wrong"
    else:
        return "Logged in successfully"
```

And here is the JQuery that is trying to output its response to the div results:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  $(function() {
    $("#sign-in").click(function() {
       $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/authentication/",
        contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
        data: { echoValue: $('input[name="username"]').val(), echoValue2: $('input[name="password"]').val() },
        success: function(data) {
            alert("working")
            alert(data)
            $('#results').text(data.value);
        }
    });     
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `return json.dumps({"value":string})`

and on the other side try to access it with the same `data.value`

you may need to parse it first

```
var json = JSON.parse(data)`
```

edit: `from flask import json`